# How to set the width of the box in BoxPlot chart in Apex charts?

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I am using **apexcharts(version 3.35.3)** in Angular project and want to set the width of the box. I have gone throught the documentation of the apexcharts and don't see any option to set the width of the box.

Is there any option to reduce the width of the box in BoxPlot chart? or any work around?

Ref Image: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it you have to add the **plotOptions** tag inside **options** and inside bar with the columnWidth property. By default the value is 70%

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      columnWidth: "40%"
      // columnWidth: "70%"
    }
  }
```

[Apexcharts documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/)

[Codesandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-thunder-6iuw1u?file=/src/BoxPlotApex.jsx)